# Update every 5 minutes a value

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am using a MySql DataBase and I want to know if there are any methods to modify a value of a column every **x** minutes/hours/days.

For example, I want to execute the following query every 5 minutes, `UPDATE table SET x=0;`.

Could I set an event or something like this from the PHPMyAdmin interface?

Comment: Yes, you can define an `event` in MySQL.

Comment: You can either set up a cron task (or cron job) from your hoster or an event in MySQL as juergen said.

Comment: use a event. it it better than a cron job. the cron job run every 5 minutes also when the db is not running and it generates then an error. the Event scheduler runs only when the DB is running

Comment: @Viorel . . . This is an X-Y problem.  I cannot think of any reasonable situation where I would want to do this.  You should ask *another* question, describing what you really want to accomplish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware about how to use PHPMyAdmin interface to create events, however, this can be done in "pure" SQL :

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS your_event_name
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
DO UPDATE table SET x=0;
```

About the part `ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE`, this will execute the event now, and then every 5 minutes, forever.

If you want to delay the execution, you can add `STARTS` after the `EVERY` statement :

```
-- This will delay the first execution in 1 hour
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

You can define when the EVENT should stop working using `ENDS` :

```
-- This will end the event in 1 week
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 WEEK
```

Of course, you can combine both `STARTS` and `ENDS`

```
-- This will end the event in 1 week
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 5 MINUTE -- Play every 5 minutes
    STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR -- Start in 1 hour
    ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 WEEK -- End in 1 week
```

If you have more than 1 query to perform in the event, you need to wrap the instructions inside `BEGIN` / `END` :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS your_event_name
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
DO
    BEGIN
        UPDATE table1 SET x=0;
        UPDATE table2 SET foo='bar';
    END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

For more informations, check the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html)

Comment: There's an "Events" tab of phpMyAdmin that can help set this up, but since the SQL query to be run gets entered directly, the GUI really only saves a few lines of SQL for setting the schedule, definer, and a few other odds and ends. Your answer is quite comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks, @Cid. It is working. That's what I looked for.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about PHPMyAdmin, but a tool like Apache NiFi can be very useful for such scheduling actions. Just use processors and set scheduling settings. For more information:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.3/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutSQL/index.html